# Unable to get access to router home page after disabling NAT

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, nat, ipv4

I have a private home network using a single **NETGEAR** cable router. I accidentally disabled NAT in the router's home page, and after that I cannot access the home page anymore.

The thing is that I was trying to fix some port-forwarding rules so I disabled the NAT feature just to experiment, and I applied the changes, it took few minutes to finish to apply the changes and then I noticed that I can't access the router home page because my IPv4 address was changed and the subnet mask and the gateway too after I turned off NAT.

Before disabling NAT I had this typical config:

- IPv4: 192.168.1.2
- Mask: 255.255.255.0
- Gateway: 192.168.1.1

Now I have something this:

- IPv4: 79.XXX.XXX.XXX
- Mask: 255.255.254.0
- Gateway: 79.XXX.XXX.1

The problem is that I can't connect to the new gateway with my web-browser to access the router's home page to re-enable NAT feature. I tried using both protocols http and https. I'm not sure if after turning off NAT maybe now I need to specify a port for the new gateway in the web-browser address bar.

I tried to unplug the router for about 30 mins to "renew" the connection but the problem persists. I also tried to run all network related Windows services and turn them to automatic startup and restarting the machine, I also tried [Complete Internet Repair](https://www.rizonesoft.com/downloads/complete-internet-repair/) and by last I tried to manually fill the IPv4 config of my network using the previous IPv4, Mask, Gateway and Google DNS servers, but If I do that my router loses connectivity so I need to rollback these changes.

Is there something I could do from my side to re-enable NAT, or the only thing I could do at this point is to call the support service of my ISP to let them re-enable NAT for me?.

Comment: There is likely a push button that must be used. Without the ability to reset the device through the web browser your only choice is to perform a a reset. The manual for the device will have more information on how to accomplish that action

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, pushing the reset button with a plug solved my problem and the NAT turned ON and the ip address and gateway returned to default. Feel free to publish a answer to mark it as the accepted one. Thank you.

Comment: "Feel free to publish a answer to mark it as the accepted one.' - The community is better served by you submitting that answer since you have all the details required to do so.